# I'm getting a POST (Internal Server Error) in Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, mongodb

I'm trying a user registration form using MEAN, but I keep getting error 500 on passing data to the database.
I tried using save instead of the register, but that doesn't hash the password.
I had this method working on a project without angular, but it's not working here.
If there is an alternative to save the data with a hashed password, that's also helpful.

This is the post code:

```
    app.post('/signup', VerifyToken, (req,res) =>
{
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    console.log(req.body);

    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty())
    {
        return res.status(422).jsonp(errors.array());
    }
    else
    {
        User = new userData( 
        {
            name: req.body.user.name,
            email: req.body.user.email,
            blood: req.body.user.blood,
            address1: req.body.user.address1,
            address2: req.body.user.address2, 
        });

        userData.register(User, req.body.user.password);
    }
});
```

This is the service that sends data:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsersService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  // getUsers()
  // {
  //   return this.http.get('');
  // }

  newUser(user)
  {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/signup',{'user' : user})
    .subscribe(data => {console.log(data)});
  }
};
```

And this is the signup component TS code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserModel } from './user.model';
import { UsersService } from '../users.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private usersService: UsersService, private router: Router) { }

  title: String = "Register as a new Donor here";
  userItem = new UserModel(null,null,null,null,null,null);
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  
  AddUser()
  {
    this.usersService.newUser(this.userItem);
    console.log("called");
    alert("success");
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  }

}
```

This is the HTML code of the signup component:

```
<div>
    <h4 class="card-header">{{title}}</h4>
</div>
<div class="container formDiv">  
    <form (ngSubmit)="AddUser()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullName" name="name" [(ngModel)]="userItem.name" placeholder="Enter Full Name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="userItem.email" placeholder="Enter Email address" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" name="blood" id="bloodType" [(ngModel)]="userItem.blood" required>
                <option value="0">Select Blood Type</option>
                <option value="A+">A+</option>
                <option value="A-">A-</option>
                <option value="B+">B+</option>
                <option value="B-">B-</option>
                <option value="O+">O+</option>
                <option value="O-">O-</option>
                <option value="AB+">AB+</option>
                <option value="AB-">AB-</option>
                <option value="Bombay">Bombay Blood group</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addressL1" name="address1" [(ngModel)]="userItem.address1" placeholder="Enter Address Line 1" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="addressL2" name="address2" [(ngModel)]="userItem.address2" placeholder="Enter Address Line 2" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="userItem.password" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confPassword" name="confPassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you also share your HTML file? We need to know if and how you use input fields since now you are just passing along an object with only null values.

Comment: 5XX errors are server side errors, there is a issue in your server side application code.

Comment: Check server side logs